# Is it known whether a constant $A$ exists, such that there is always a Carmichael-number between $x$ and $Ax$ for $x\ge 561$?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, recreational-mathematics, pseudoprimes

For prime numbers, such a constant is well known. For $n\ge 2$, there is always
a prime between $n$ and $2n$, so $A=2$ does the job.

Carmichael-numbers are much rarer, so I wonder, whether a constant $A$ has been found and be proven to do the job for $n\ge 561$ ?

The count upto $10^{21}$ shows that there are Carmichael-numbers with $3,4,5,...,21$ digits, so is $A=10$ sufficient ?

Comment: I dk. I am not familiar with the proof that there is no largest Carmichael number but I suggest you look it up to see if there's any clue in it. Might or might not help. I dk whether there any results about the asymptotic density of C. nos.

Answer (score 2):

Carmichael-numbers are not so rare as it perhaps seems. If $C(x)$ denotes the number of Carmichael numbers $\le x$, then Harman proved in $2005$ that $C(x)>x^{0.332}$ for $x$ sufficiently large. Erdös has even conjectured that there are $x^{1-o(1)}$ Carmichael numbers for $x$ sufficiently large, although present computations do not really point to this. From the asymptotic density one could obtain such a constant $A$.

Comment: That would at least give an $A$ for sufficiently large $x$. Unfortunately, I nowhere found a concrete number $y$, such that $C(x)>x^{0.332}$ for all $x\ge y$. And Erdös's density has not been proven. The situation is similar for the upper bounds of $C(x)$. I nowhere found concrete bounds.

Comment: I have no access to Harman's paper right now, did you check it for such a $y$ ? It might not be known, after all.

Comment: I found a paper where the idea is described, but they only claimed that there is a computable number $y$ depending on the exponent, but I found no computation, not even for $\large C(x)>x^{\frac{2}{7}}$